Modify Guild Channel Positions
Good day everyone, I am trying to to make a code based to php
to move discord channel postion from category to other category.
here is my code
<?php 

    //move channel to archive
    
    $url = "https://discord.com/api/v10/guilds/$discordID/channels";

    $data = array(
         'id'  => 'xxxxx', //channel ID
         'parent_id'  => "xxxxxx" //new category
    );
    $data_json = json_encode($data);
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
       'Authorization: Bot xxxxxxxx',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json)
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $response;
    curl_close($ch);



?>

I got this error

{"message": "Invalid Form Body", "code": 50035, "errors": {"_errors":
[{"code": "LIST_TYPE_CONVERT", "message": "Only iterables may be used
in a ListType"}]}}

I am following information provided here
https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#modify-guild-channel-positions
`    <?php
    //move channel to archive
    
    $url = "https://discord.com/api/v10/guilds/$discordID/channels";

    $data = array(
         'id'  => 'xxxxx', //channel ID
         'parent_id'  => "xxxxxx" //new category
    );
    $data_json = json_encode($data);
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
       'Authorization: Bot xxxxxxxx',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json)
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $response;
    curl_close($ch);



?>`


If I understand the documentation correctly, the PATCH method can be used to modify multiple channels at once, so it is looking for an array of objects: https://3v4l.org/c8MEG

This is further backed by samples in this issue and this postman
